# sql - update statement from another table

Tags: sql

Can anyone help with the following select statement?

I have 2 tables and I need to update table#1 with data from table#2

The field to update is 'amount'

Table#1

```
      date         amount
1    2015-05-01     0
2    2015-05-02     0
3    2015-05-03     0
4    2015-05-04     0
5    2015-05-05     0
6    2015-05-06     0
7    2015-05-07     0
8    2015-05-08     0
```

table#2

```
        date      amount
1    2015-05-01     12
2    2015-05-04     23
3    2015-05-07     30
```

the update statement should take table#2 to update table#1 and this is how it should look like:

table#1

```
      date         amount
1    2015-05-01     12
2    2015-05-02     12
3    2015-05-03     12
4    2015-05-04     23
5    2015-05-05     23
6    2015-05-06     23
7    2015-05-07     30
8    2015-05-08     30
```

Comment: Have u tried anything yourself?

Comment: `UPDATE ... JOIN` can vary from vendor to vendor.  Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: yes I have tried but without sucess.

Comment: The RDBMS is SQL express 2012

Comment: what db server? and where did you get row 8. 2015-05-08 from?

Comment: I just added an extra line in Table#1  containing 2015-05-08    0   ... sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard way to do this is using a correlated subquery:

```
update t1
    set amount = (select top 1 t2.amount
                  from t2
                  where t2.date <= t1.date
                  order by t2.date
                 );
```

The `top` might vary from database to database.